# Limiting size of float

Tags: c++

I have an array of floats that are all different lengths, and have a decimal point in various places. ex:

0.2345

52.6

208567

Is there a way to force them all to be the same length, so that when I write them to a text file they line up on both left and right side? my current output code:

```
for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
    fileout<< numbers[i] << "\n";
    }
```

fileout is made from ofstream

Comment: read the documentation maybe?

Comment: You don't want to modify the `float` values to make them the same "length"; you want to control how the values are printed as text.

Comment: Maybe you need this [setf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) or [setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to get the string representation of the float, and [`std::string::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/) to resize that string to your preferred length, e.g.:

```
std::string str = std::to_string(numbers[i]);
str.resize(len, '0');
fileout << str << '\n';
```

If `str.size()` is smaller than `len` then the above will append zeros to make it long enough. If `str.size()` is greater than `len` then it will remove the last digits from the string.

Comment: Is to_string guaranteed to return a string containing a decimal point? Otherwise you could end up resizing "1" into "10000" which is wrong.

Comment: @immibis Yes it's guaranteed to return a string with a decimal point followed by 6 digits.

Comment: The one problem with this idea is that it may create `1000000.` i.e. a trailing decimal point.

Comment: @MSalters But if the input is `1000000` and the `len` is 8 what else should it do? With this approach the `len` just needs to be set large enough to not produce unwanted output.

Comment: Well, `1.000E+08` is also 8 long. Not suggesting that's the best answer, I'm not the one asking the question.